# My firebase Realtime app does not close in a single click

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am making an app based on firebase Realtime database. I have two firebase recycler view in my app. When I test it on my physical device it runs smoothly. But when I try to close it , it reopens automatically. I have to repeat the same thing  multiple times to actually close it successfully.
I am using the following code to close it.

```
  btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainLoginActivity.this.finish();
                System.exit(0);
                fbAuth.signOut();

            }
        });
```

**Edit**
I think I have to close the **IndexMenuActivity** as many times as I have opened it.I tried the following code to finish it and start the new activity.

```
 btnLook01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(IndexMenuActivity.this, View1DataActivity.class)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                IndexMenuActivity.this.finish();
```

I hope a practical solution.

Comment: Probably not the cause of this problem, but you'll want to put `fbAuth.signOut();` before `System.exit(0)` as right now it'll never get executed.

Comment: You're not supposed to use `System.exit()` at all on Android.

Comment: You are right @ Frank van Pufflen that *Probably not the cause of this problem* because I have tested it.

Comment: `System.exit(0);` shuts down the JVM. So in Android, you should not use this statement.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo for guidance. What can be the reason behind my problem?